# Configuration doesn't pick connection string from secrets.json file in ASP NET Core MVC 6.0 lts

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I created ASP NET Core MVC 6 lts app with individual user accounts with Visual Studio 2022 preview 6.0. I moved connection string from appsettings.json to secrets.json. I start the app with IIS Express and apply migrations from exception page that opens. It works.

But when I try to apply additional migrations from Package Manager Console I get an error "connectionString can't be null".

Add services to the container. This is from `Program.cs`:

```
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();
```

This is `appsettings.json`, connection string value removed:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": ""
},
```

This is `Secrets.json`:

```
{
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=DESKTOP-HIPPIDT;Initial Catalog=KehittajaLocalDb;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you added `builder.AddUserSecrets<Program>();`?You can try to refer to the official doc about [Access a secret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=windows#access-a-secret).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Yiyi You. Docs refer to start up class which does not exist in 6.0. The point here is that 6.0 does not call "CreateDefaultBuilder" which added user secrets automatically. I think.

Answer (score 1):

In **.NET 6**,

You do not need to specify `AddUserSecrets<>`.
As mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=windows) ,

> WebApplication.CreateBuilder initializes a new instance of the
> WebApplicationBuilder class with preconfigured defaults. The
> initialized WebApplicationBuilder (builder) provides default
> configuration and calls AddUserSecrets when the EnvironmentName is
> Development

All you need to do is get the connection string from the `builder.Configuration` like below:

```
var dbConnectionString = builder.Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DevelopmentConnection"];
```

Then, you can specify the connection with `AddDbContext<>`:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    {
        options.UseSqlServer(dbConnectionString);
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

I added this to the Program.cs, now it works as expected. I don't know how come it worked when migrations were applied from exception page "Apply Migrations" button anyway.

```
// Add services to the container

if(builder.Enviroment.IsDevelopment())
{
    builder.Configuration.AddUserSecrets<Program>();
}

 ..other code
```